# Socket: When player in a room closes browser, how server can correctly emit to other sockets in that room?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, serversocket, chatroom

Please, read to the end, help me!

I'm developing a multiroom game using SocketIO, with a client-side (React) and a server-side (Node). I'm having a problem on handling this situation:

Consider that at least two clients are inside a Room, after have joining it with `socket.join(roomId)` (at server-side).

**Situation 1**: When a player leaves the room manually (clicking a button in the page), the client-side does `socket.emit("playerLeaving", someVar)` to the server-side listener `socket.on("playerLeaving", doStuff)` that do some important things with the database *(let's call it **X listener**)*. Then this listener fires back an event to the other client sockets in that room, with `io.sockets.in(roomID).emit("playerLeft", someVar)`. No problem here.

**Situation 2**: Instead of manually leaving that room, that user just close the tab/browser, which fires a "disconnect" event do the server-side. Event in that case, the server must do the same procedure that he did on 1st situation, inside that ***X listener***, so I just tried to emit this event `socket.emit("playerLeaving", roomID)` from inside the "disconnect" handler at server-side, so the ***X listener*** would receive it, do his stuffs, and broadcast to the other players that someone has left that room.

**THE PROBLEM**: the "disconnect" handler (at server-side) emits to ***X listener*** (also server-side), but this one doesn't receives it. Summin up, when a player in a room closes the tab/browser, the server isn't handling it correctly and consequently the other players in that room doesn't even get to know about that.

MY CODE:

**SERVER-SIDE**:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    socket.on("playerJoiningRoom", (roomID) => {
      socket.join(roomID); // to sign socket to a room
      // .... some code
      io.broadcast.to(roomID).emit("someoneJoined", someVar); // this works fine
    })

    // X-listener
    socket.on("playerLeaving", (someVar) => {
      // ... do stuff in database
      io.sockets.in(roomID).emit("playerLeft", otherVar);
    }

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      // ...some code here
      // then, emit to the listener above
      // example:  socket.emit("playerLeaving", someVar);

    });

  })

}
```

**CLIENT-SIDE**

```
function socketEnteredRoom(socket, roomID) {
    // notify server
    socket.emit("playerJoiningRoom", roomID);

    // listen to other players joining the room
    socket.on("someoneJoined", someVar);

    // listen to other players leaving the room. This listener works when some player leave manually (leave button), but don't work when a player closes tab/browser
    socket.on("someoneLeft", someVar);
}

// when player wants to exit room
function handlerExitRoom() {
   socket.emit("playerLeaving", someVar);
}
```

Waiting for your help! Thank you!
(sorry if this is a repeated question, but I couldn't find a answer that worked)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure since I can't see your full code, but a common issue is people try to emit to rooms their socket is in in `disconnect` but the socket is no longer in any rooms at this point. Try changing to `disconnect` to `disconnecting`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
//server-side
socket.on("disconnect", () => {
  io.emit("playerLeaving", someVar);
});


//client-side
socket.emit("disconnect", () => {
  
});
```